# Navigating to commonly used folders by right click?

Tags: windows-vista

So is there a way I can navigate to common folders by right clicking?  I want this to work in explorer and open/save file dialogs.  I use windows vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Direct Folders](http://www.codesector.com/directfolders.php) to do this.  By default, you middle-click or double-click on a blank area in the folder (e.g., Windows Explorer, *Save As...* dialog, *Open File* dialog, or even your desktop), and you get a menu with your recently-used folders and preconfigured "common" folders.

Comment: Yea, direct folders seems to do what I want and appears to have a functional version for free.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for but maybe helps. I do not know about vista but in server 2003 it works like this:

In the open / save dialog on the left side there are some shortcut icons (desktop, my files, ...) and there is a way to add and remove entries to this list.

I do not remember how it works now, but if you are interested I could check.

But the number of entries in this list is limited.